# Out of memory error. Allocating...

Tags: gprof

I'm trying to use a gprof command: `gprof -s executable.exe gmon.out gmon.sum` to merge profiling data gathered from 2 runs of my programs. But the following error appears:

> gprof: out of memory allocating 3403207348 bytes after a total of 196608 bytes

My program is quite simple (just one `for` loop). If i run it once, the run time is too short (it shows 0.00s) for gprof to record.

In CygWin, I do the following steps:

1. gcc -pg -o fl forAndWhilLoop.c
2. fl (run the program)
3. mv gmon.out gmon.sum
4. fl (run the program)
5. gprof -s fl.exe gmon.out gmon.sum
6. gprof fl.exe gmon.sum>gmon.out
7. gprof fl.exe

My program:

```
int main(void)
{
    int fac=1;
    int count=10;
    int k;

    for(k=1;k<=count;k++)
    {
        fac = fac * k;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Post all your steps.  Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to time it, on my machine it's **105ns**. Here's the code:

```
void forloop(void){ 
    int fac=1; 
    int count=10; 
    int k; 

    for(k=1;k<=count;k++) 
    { 
        fac = fac * k; 
    } 
} 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
        forloop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Get the idea? I used a hand-held stopwatch. Since it runs 10^9 times, seconds = nanoseconds.

Unrolling the inner loop like this reduced the time to **92ns**;

```
int k = 1;
while(k+5 <= count){
    fac *= k * (k+1) * (k+2) * (k+3) * (k+4);
    k += 5;
}
while(k <= count){
    fac *= k++;
}
```

Switching to Release build from Debug brought it down to **21ns**. You can only expect that kind of speedup in an actual hotspot, which this is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **pprof** instead of **gprof** should be executed